# How can I resize gifs discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I tried to make a ".kiss" command
I cant figure out how to size the gifs.

```
 module.exports = {
    name:'kiss',
    description:'Smoochy smoochies! ',
    additionalInfo:`<user>`,
    aliases:'',
    execute(client,msg,args){
        const author = msg.author
        const authorMember = msg.member
        const user = msg.mentions.users.first()
        const userMember = msg.mentions.members.first()
        const authorOrUser = user || author
        const authorOrUserMember = userMember|| authorMember
        const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        if (!user){
            msg.reply('You need to provide a user!')
        }else{
        const gifs = [
            "https://c.tenor.com/F02Ep3b2jJgAAAAS/cute-kawai.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/BjwmxFVGKm0AAAAS/toloveru-unexpected.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/0mdCwkmGD1oAAAAS/kiss-love.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/Hcvab1NgNdkAAAAS/kiss-anime.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/VTvkMN6P648AAAAM/anime-kiss.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/SqpFZQfcyEgAAAAM/anime-kiss.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/OPUTh1nbf7YAAAAM/anime-kiss.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/3wE3JNW0fswAAAAM/anime-kiss-love.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/36NbjGxwOT8AAAAM/anime-kissing.gif"
        ]
        const gif = `${gifs[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifs.length)]}?size=4096`
        embed.setTitle(`${author.username} kisses ${user.username}! How cute `)
        embed.setImage(gif)
        embed.setColor('BLUE')
        msg.reply({embeds : [embed] })
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is it returns the code above when the file gets required (I have a advanced command handler).
I've tried to do "?size=4096" but that doesn't work.
Can somebody help me size the gifs.
Please and thano you

Answer (score 0):

you cannot resize that gifs because the gifs is under 4096.
Please search an gifs that is 4096 size.

### Tips:

You can use a [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) for the alternative.

This is the code if you want.

```js
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "kiss",
  description: "Smoochy smoochies! ",
  additionalInfo: `<user>`,
  aliases: "",
  async execute(client, msg, args) {
    const author = msg.author;
    const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if (!user) {
      msg.reply("You need to provide a user!");
    } else {
      let image = "";

      const { body } = await superagent.get(
        "https://neko-love.xyz/api/v1/kiss"
      );

      image = body.url;

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${author.username} kisses ${user.username}! How cute `)
        .setImage(image)
        .setColor("BLUE");

      msg.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
  },
};
```

> Note: The url is not a gifs. Sorry!